# CRUD: Update 2 files on server and mySQL record

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, updates, crud

I have a form built out in which you can upload two files with your record, and the files will save to the server, and the information will be inputted into the mySQL database. The files upload and delete successfully now, but I cannot get the "update" functionality working. I want the old files to be deleted from the server, the new ones uploaded, and the information updated in the mySQL database.

I currently receive this error:

> Error: `visible` = 'N', `homepage` = 'N', `fa_id` = '', `title` = 'tester', `caption` = '', `url` = '', `month` = '', `date` = '', `year` = '', `summary` = '', `full_text` = '', `image` = '51837-', `image_type` = '', `image_size` = '0' `file` = '34076-', `file_type` = '', `file_size` = '0' WHERE `events`.`id` = 44 LIMIT 1

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/session.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/db_connection.php");?>
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION["login_user"] != true) {
    echo("Access denied!");
    exit();
}
?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/validation_functions.php");?>
<?php find_selected_event_page(); ?>
<?php
  if (!$current_event) {
    // page ID was missing or invalid or 
    // page couldn't be found in database
    redirect_to("manage_content.php");
  }
?>
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Process the form

    // validations
    $required_fields = array("visible");
    validate_presences($required_fields);   


    if (empty($errors)) {

    // Perform Update
        $id = $current_event["id"];
        $visible = mysql_prep($_POST["visible"]);
        $homepage = mysql_prep($_POST["homepage"]);
        $fa_id = mysql_prep($_POST["fa_id"]);
        $title = mysql_prep($_POST["title"]);
        $caption = mysql_prep($_POST["caption"]);
        $url = mysql_prep($_POST["url"]);
        $month = mysql_prep($_POST["month"]);
        $date = mysql_prep($_POST["date"]);
        $year = mysql_prep($_POST["year"]);
        $summary = mysql_prep($_POST["summary"]);
        $full_text = mysql_prep($_POST["full_text"]);
    $image = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $image_loc = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
        $image_folder="images/";
        $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $file_folder="files/";

 $image_new_size = $image_size/1024;  
 $file_new_size = $file_size/1024;  
 $new_image_name = strtolower($image);
 $new_file_name = strtolower($file);


 $final_image=str_replace(' ','-',$new_image_name);
 $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

         if(file_exists("files/".$current_event['file']))
{
unlink("files/".$current_event['file']);
}

    if(file_exists("images/".$current_event['image']))
{
unlink("images/".$current_event['image']);
}

  if(move_uploaded_file($image_loc,$image_folder.$final_image))
 if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$file_folder.$final_file))


        $query  = "UPDATE `events` SET ";
        $query .= "`visible` = '{$visible}', ";
        $query .= "`homepage` = '{$homepage}', ";
        $query .= "`fa_id` = '{$fa_id}', ";
        $query .= "`title` = '{$title}', ";
        $query .= "`caption` = '{$caption}', ";
        $query .= "`url` = '{$url}', ";
        $query .= "`month` = '{$month}', ";
        $query .= "`date` = '{$date}', ";
        $query .= "`year` = '{$year}', ";
        $query .= "`summary` = '{$summary}', ";
        $query .= "`full_text` = '{$full_text}', ";
        $query .= "`image` = '{$final_image}', ";
        $query .= "`image_type` = '{$image_type}', ";
        $query .= "`image_size` = '{$image_new_size}' ";
        $query .= "`file` = '{$final_file}', ";
        $query .= "`file_type` = '{$file_type}', ";
        $query .= "`file_size` = '{$file_new_size}' ";
        $query .= "WHERE `events`.`id` = {$id} ";
        $query .= "LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection) >= 0) {

            // Success
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Item updated.";
            redirect_to("manage_content.php");
        } else {
            // Failure
            //$_SESSION["message"] = "Item creation failed.";
        //redirect_to("new_news.php");
        echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $result->error;

        }

    }
} else {
    // This is probably a GET request

} // end: if (isset($_POST['submit']))

?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");?>
<?php find_selected_event_page(); ?>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Washington Jesuit Adacemy: A high quality and comprehensive middle school for 5th through 8th grade boys from low-income communities in the DC metro area.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Washington Jesuit Academy">
  <title>Washington Jesuit Academy: About</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cloud.typography.com/6113114/6497572/css/fonts.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cloud.typography.com/683054/7063952/css/fonts.css"/>
  <link href="/assets/css/wja.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="/assets/css/wja-startup.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/navigation.php");?>
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    theme: 'modern',
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
      'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
      'save table contextmenu directionality template paste textcolor'
    ],
    content_css: 'css/content.css',
    menubar: 'edit view format',
    style_formats: [
    {title: 'Blocks', items: [
      {title: 'Paragraph', format: 'p'},
    ]},
    {title: 'Headers', items: [
      {title: 'Header 1', format: 'h1'},
      {title: 'Header 2', format: 'h2'},
      {title: 'Header 3', format: 'h3'},
      {title: 'Header 4', format: 'h4'},
      {title: 'Header 5', format: 'h5'},
      {title: 'Header 6', format: 'h6'}
    ]},
    {title: 'Alignment', items: [
      {title: 'Left', icon: 'alignleft', format: 'alignleft'},
      {title: 'Center', icon: 'aligncenter', format: 'aligncenter'},
      {title: 'Right', icon: 'alignright', format: 'alignright'},
      {title: 'Justify', icon: 'alignjustify', format: 'alignjustify'}
    ]}
  ],
    toolbar: 'removeformat | bold italic | bullist numlist outdent indent | link anchor | nonbreaking charmap hr | print preview fullpage | code'
  });
  </script>
<div class="content">
<div class="block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col=md-12">
      <?php // $message is just a variable, doesn't use the SESSION
            if (!empty($message)) {
                echo "<div class=\"message\">" . htmlentities($message) .  "</div>";
            }
        ?>
      <?php echo form_errors($errors); ?>
      <h2>Edit item</h2>
      <form action="edit_event.php?event=<?php echo urlencode($current_event["id"]); ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="visible" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Published</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="visible" id="visible1" value="N" <?php if ($current_event["visible"] == "N") { echo "checked"; } ?>>
              No </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="visible" id="visible2" value="Y" <?php if ($current_event["visible"] == "Y") { echo "checked"; } ?>>
              Yes </label>
            <p class="small">If &lsquo;Yes&rsquo; is selected, the item will be publicly visible on the website as soon as it is saved.</p>
          </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="homepage" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Featured on Homepage</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="homepage" id="homepage1" value="N" <?php if ($current_event["homepage"] == "N") { echo "checked"; } ?>>
              No </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="homepage" id="homepage2" value="Y" <?php if ($current_event["homepage"] == "Y") { echo "checked"; } ?>>
              Yes </label>
            <p class="small">If &lsquo;Yes&rsquo; is selected, the item will also be featured on the <strong>homepage</strong>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>     

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fa_id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Form Assembly ID</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fa_id" value="<?php echo htmlentities($current_event["fa_id"]); ?>" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="month" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Month</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="month" value="">
              <option value="">Select Month</option>
              <option value="01" <?php if ($current_event["month"] == "January") { echo "selected"; } ?>>January</option>
              <option value="02" <?php if ($current_event["month"] == "February") { echo "selected"; } ?>>February</option>
              <option value="02" <?php if ($current_event["month"] == "March") { echo "selected"; } ?>>March</option>
              <option value="04" <?php if ($current_event["month"] == "April") { echo "selected"; } ?>>April</option>
              <option value="05" <?php if ($current_event["month"] == "May") { echo "selected"; } ?>>May</option>
              <option value="06" <?php if ($current_event["month"] == "June") { echo "selected"; } ?>>June</option>
              <option value="07" <?php if ($current_event["month"] == "July") { echo "selected"; } ?>>July</option>
              <option value="08" <?php if ($current_event["month"] == "August") { echo "selected"; } ?>>August</option>
              <option value="09" <?php if ($current_event["month"] == "September") { echo "selected"; } ?>>September</option>
              <option value="10" <?php if ($current_event["month"] == "October") { echo "selected"; } ?>>October</option>
              <option value="11" <?php if ($current_event["month"] == "November") { echo "selected"; } ?>>November</option>
              <option value="12" <?php if ($current_event["month"] == "December") { echo "selected"; } ?>>December</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
           <div class="form-group">
          <label for="month" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="month" value="">
              <option value="">Select date</option>
              <option value="1" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "1") { echo "selected"; } ?>>1</option>
              <option value="2" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "2") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2</option>
              <option value="3" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "3") { echo "selected"; } ?>>3</option>
              <option value="4" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "4") { echo "selected"; } ?>>4</option>
              <option value="5" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "5") { echo "selected"; } ?>>5</option>
              <option value="6" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "6") { echo "selected"; } ?>>6</option>
              <option value="7" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "7") { echo "selected"; } ?>>7</option>
              <option value="8" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "8") { echo "selected"; } ?>>8</option>
              <option value="9" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "9") { echo "selected"; } ?>>9</option>
              <option value="10" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "10") { echo "selected"; } ?>>10</option>
              <option value="11" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "11") { echo "selected"; } ?>>11</option>
              <option value="12" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "12") { echo "selected"; } ?>>12</option>
              <option value="13" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "13") { echo "selected"; } ?>>13</option>
              <option value="14" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "14") { echo "selected"; } ?>>14</option>
              <option value="15" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "15") { echo "selected"; } ?>>15</option>
              <option value="16" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "16") { echo "selected"; } ?>>16</option>
              <option value="17" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "17") { echo "selected"; } ?>>17</option>
              <option value="18" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "18") { echo "selected"; } ?>>18</option>
              <option value="19" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "19") { echo "selected"; } ?>>19</option>
              <option value="20" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "20") { echo "selected"; } ?>>20</option>
              <option value="21" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "21") { echo "selected"; } ?>>21</option>
              <option value="22" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "22") { echo "selected"; } ?>>22</option>
              <option value="23" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "23") { echo "selected"; } ?>>23</option>
              <option value="24" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "24") { echo "selected"; } ?>>24</option>
              <option value="25" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "25") { echo "selected"; } ?>>25</option>
              <option value="26" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "26") { echo "selected"; } ?>>26</option>
              <option value="27" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "27") { echo "selected"; } ?>>27</option>
              <option value="28" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "28") { echo "selected"; } ?>>28</option>
              <option value="29" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "29") { echo "selected"; } ?>>29</option>
              <option value="30" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "30") { echo "selected"; } ?>>30</option>
              <option value="31" <?php if ($current_event["date"] == "31") { echo "selected"; } ?>>31</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="year" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Year</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="year" value="<?php echo htmlentities($current_event["year"]); ?>">
              <option value="">Select Year</option>
              <option value="2000" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2000") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2000</option>
              <option value="2001" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2001") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2001</option>
              <option value="2002" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2002") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2002</option>
              <option value="2003" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2003") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2003</option>
              <option value="2004" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2004") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2004</option>
              <option value="2005" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2005") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2005</option>
              <option value="2006" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2006") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2006</option>
              <option value="2007" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2007") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2007</option>
              <option value="2008" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2008") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2008</option>
              <option value="2009" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2009") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2009</option>
              <option value="2010" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2010") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2010</option>
              <option value="2011" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2011") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2011</option>
              <option value="2012" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2012") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2012</option>
              <option value="2013" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2013") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2013</option>
              <option value="2014" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2014") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2014</option>
              <option value="2015" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2015") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2015</option>
              <option value="2016" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2016") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2016</option>
              <option value="2017" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2017") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2017</option>
              <option value="2018" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2018") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2018</option>
              <option value="2019" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2019") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2019</option>
              <option value="2020" <?php if ($current_event["year"] == "2020") { echo "selected"; } ?>>2020</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<?php echo htmlentities($current_event["title"]); ?>" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="author" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Caption</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="caption" value="<?php echo htmlentities($current_event["caption"]); ?>" />
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="url" class="col-sm-2 control-label">External URL</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="url" value="<?php echo htmlentities($current_event["url"]); ?>" />
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="summary" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Summary</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="summary" value="<?php echo htmlentities($current_event["summary"]); ?>" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group margin-t-25">
          <label for="full_text" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Full Text</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea name="full_text" rows="10" style="width:100%"><?php echo htmlentities($current_event["full_text"]); ?></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group"><hr />
   <label for="full_text" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image Upload</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="file" name="image" class="mt-3"/> <?php if ($current_event["image"] != NULL) : ; ?> 
 <?php echo $current_event['file']; ?><?php endif ?>
       </div>  </div>
        <div class="form-group"><hr />
   <label for="full_text" class="col-sm-2 control-label">File Upload</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="file" name="file" class="mt-3"/> <?php if ($current_event["file"] != NULL) : ; ?> 
 <?php echo $current_event['file']; ?><?php endif ?>
       </div>  </div>
        <div class="text-right">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-t-md m-r" value="Save changes" />
          <a href="manage_content.php" class="btn btn-default m-t-md">Cancel</a><br>
          <a href="delete_event.php?event=<?php echo urlencode($current_event["id"]); ?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure? This can&rsquo;t be undone.');" class="btn btn-danger m-t-md">Delete item</a></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/footer.php");?>
<!-- JavaScript --> 
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../assets/js/toolkit.js"></script> 
<script src="../assets/js/application.js"></script>
</div>
</body></html><?php
  // Close database connection
  if (isset($connection)) {
  mysqli_close($connection);
  }
?>
```

Comment: Echo the SQL statement after it's built. You don't need the {} around the var names since you're inside double quotes.

Comment: What would I need to echo for an update? Removed the { } -thank you

Comment: echo "<pre>".$query."</pre>";

Comment: Still receiving same error..

Comment: What was echoed for the query???